# How to select only second class in python scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Bzs.png) https://televize.heureka.cz/samsung-qe43q60b
I'm trying to get content from only one class, but they are twice here and I'm unable to find answer anywhere on the internet for more than hour.

Website:

```
-- something before --
    <div class="c-offers-list__cont">
        <div>some content</div>
    </div>
-- something in between --
    <div class="c-offers-list__cont">
    <div>the content I want</div>
</div>
-- something after --
```

For now I just get both contents and I only want the second one. Anyone knows how to select only the second class? Thank you.

I have tried
`for x in soup.find_all('img', {'class':'c-offers-list'})...` but it shows both values.
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkT06.png)

My code now:

```py
import requests, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd

def program():
    try:
        arg = sys.argv[1:]
        if len(arg) == 3:
            category = arg[0]; brand = arg[1]; model = arg[2]
            url = 'https://'+category+'.heureka.cz/'+brand+'-'+model
        else:
            print('Syntax: python program.py <kategorie> <značka> <model>')
            print('Příklad: python program.py televize samsung qe43q60b')
            sys.exit(1)
        page = requests.get(url)
        brandlist = []; valuelist = []; shipcost = []; res = {}
        if page.status_code == 200:
            try:
                soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
                
                # add clicking buttons to show full website
                
                #if soup.find('e-button'):
                #soup.find('c-offers-list__more-button').click()
                
                # select only second c-offers-list__cont
                
                for x in soup.find_all('img', {'class':'c-offer__shop-logo'}):
                    brandlist.append(x['alt'].rstrip())
                for x in soup.find_all('span', {'class':'c-offer__price'}):
                    valuelist.append(''.join(x.contents[0].split()[:-1]))
                for x in soup.find_all('span', {'data-cy':'delivery-badge'}):
                    shipcost.append(x.get_text().replace('\xa0', '').replace('Kč',''))
                res = dict(map(lambda i,j : (i,j) , brandlist,valuelist))

                ship = dict(map(lambda i,j : (i,j) , brandlist,shipcost))
                # TEST
                class Shop:
                    brand = []; value = []; shipcost = []
                    def __init__(self, value, shipcost):
                        self.value = value
                        self.shipcost = shipcost

                    def Display(self):
                        print(self.name+': '+value+',- doprava '+shipcost)
                #shop = brand(

                minvalue_shop = min(res, key=res.get)
                maxvalue_shop = max(res, key=res.get)
                minvalue = int(min(res.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[1])
                maxvalue = int(max(res.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[1])

                print('\nPRODUKT: '+category+' '+brand+' '+model)
                print('Počet zapsaných hodnot: '+str(len(res))+'\n')
                # TEST
                df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(brandlist, valuelist, shipcost)),
                    columns=['Eshop','Cena','Doprava'])
                print(df.sort_values(by=['Cena']).to_string(index=False, header=False))
                print('\nStatistiky:\n')
                print(' Minimální cena: '+str(minvalue)+' na '+minvalue_shop)
                print(' Maximální cena: '+str(maxvalue)+' na '+maxvalue_shop)
                print(' Rozdíl cen: '+str((maxvalue) - (minvalue)))
            except:
                raise
    except IndexError:
        sys.exit(1)
# instructions
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        program()
    except TypeError:
        print('Produkt neexistuje.')
        raise
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Please add your code directly to the question.

Comment: It was formatted wrong, now correctly.

Comment: I mean your Python code. The code included in the last line have nothing to do with `.c-offers-list__cont`.

Comment: You took a screenshot of your Python code; please copy and paste those into the question itself as text.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to know, if you have a list `[a, b]`, how to get `b`?

Comment: There is 2 classes named c-offers-list__cont. I am only able to get content of both these classes, because I am unable to select the second c-offers-list__cont. I really don't understand how more easily should I explain it.

Comment: `results = soup.find_all(...)` and then `second_result = results[1]`?

Comment: I want to select this second class only [class](https://imgur.com/a/xt9Jk65)

Answer (score 0):

soup.find_all() returns a list of elements. You can then pick the element you want by accessing it in the list.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, find_all() shows both values, but I only need the second one.

Comment: so take the second one

Comment: But the question is how?

Comment: @Samuraj How did you take the second one from the `arg` list?

Comment: @Samuraj you can take the second item in the list by accessing it like this:
test_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
second = test_list[1]. I strongly encourage you to look for information about working with lists in python, as they are very important not only for webscraping, but also for programming in general

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it with

```py
raw = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'c-offers-list__cont'})[1]
for x in raw.find_all('img', {'class':'c-offer__shop-logo'}):
    brandlist.append(x['alt'].rstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to get your goal - Indeed you can select from `ResultSet` by index:

```
soup.select('.c-offers-list__cont')[1]
```

Selecting your elements more specific is the cleaner solution - This one is using [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) searches for the text of the heading and its sibling:

```
soup.select_one(':-soup-contains("Nejlevnější nabídky") + .c-offers-list__cont')
```

or use `:not()` to exclude the first list by a specific class it is using:

```
soup.select_one(':not(.c-offers-list__bidding-heading) + .c-offers-list__cont')
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(
    'https://televize.heureka.cz/samsung-qe43q60b').text)

soup.select_one(':-soup-contains("Nejlevnější nabídky") + .c-offers-list__cont')
# soup.select_one(':not(.c-offers-list__bidding-heading) + .c-offers-list__cont')
# soup.select('.c-offers-list__cont')[1]
```